# How to use mybatis get result type as a list after select from database

Tags: java, mybatis

In my project I use mybatis as dao and I want to get the result which an arraylist of the select row from database for example

I have an Employee class and a dao interface Employee.java

```
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String sex;
  private String phonenumber;
}
```

EmpInterface.java

```
public interface EmpInterface {
   public ArrayList<Employeer> selectAll();
}
```

How should I write the select tag in `mapper.xml` of mybatis?

Comment: You should be clearer e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640551/how-to-write-select-tag-form-mybatis-select for others to help you

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="package.Employee">
    <id     column="ID"           jdbcType="NUMERIC" property="id" />
    <result column="NAME"         jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="name" />
    <result column="SEX"          jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="sex" />
    <result column="PHONE_NUMBER" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="phonenumber" />
</resultMap>
<select id="selectAll" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
  SELECT 
    emp.ID,
    emp.NAME,
    emp.SEX,
    emp.PHONE_NUMBER
  FROM EMPLOYEES emp
</select>
```